# ActiveMQ messages from the topic are not received

Tags: java, properties, activemq-classic, publish-subscribe

I am having a weird situation. I am listening to a topic

I am able to listen to the message as long as the server is up and running. But the soon I stop server and messages are arriving in the queue and when the server is up again I am not able to consume those messages.

```
@Configuration
public class ConnectionFactoryConfig {
    @Value("${jsa.activemq.broker.url}")
    String brokerUrl;

    @Value("${jsa.activemq.borker.username}")
    String userName;

    @Value("${jsa.activemq.borker.password}")
    String password;

    /*
     * Initial ConnectionFactory
     */
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(brokerUrl);
        connectionFactory.setUserName(userName);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(password);

        return connectionFactory;
    }

    //  @Bean // Serialize message content to json using TextMessage
    public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
//      converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> jsaFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                     DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setPubSubDomain(true);
//      factory.setMessageConverter(jacksonJmsMessageConverter());
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
        factory.setSubscriptionDurable(true);
        factory.setClientId("TEST_CLIENT");

        return factory;
    }
}
```

**Subscriber**

```
@Component
public class JmsSubcriber {

    @JmsListener(destination = "${jsa.activemq.topic}")
    public void receive(String msg) {

        System.out.println(new Date() + "::Recieved Message: " + msg);
    }
}
```

**Property files**

> jsa.activemq.broker.url=tcp://localhost:61616
>
> jsa.activemq.borker.username=admin jsa.activemq.borker.password=admin
>
> jsa.activemq.topic=jsa-topic spring.jms.pub-sub-domain=true

See the messages in the queue I can se

[image]

But on starting the server I am not getting it.